# Mediawiki error: File upload not working

Tags: rhel, media, wiki

I've installed Mediawiki v1.24.1 on my server which is running RHEL7. 
I've installed it under `/var/www/foohelp/wiki`. However, when I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
[f3eae72a] /foohelp/wiki/index.php/Special:Upload Exception from line 1871 of /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/filerepo/file/LocalFile.php: Could not acquire lock for 'User-default.png.'
Backtrace:
#0 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/filerepo/file/LocalFile.php(1174): LocalFile->lock()
#1 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/upload/UploadBase.php(738): LocalFile->upload(string, string, string, integer, array, boolean, User)
#2 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/specials/SpecialUpload.php(467): UploadBase->performUpload(string, string, boolean, User)
#3 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/specials/SpecialUpload.php(186): SpecialUpload->processUpload()
#4 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(363): SpecialUpload->execute(NULL)
#5 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(584): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#6 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/MediaWiki.php(275): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#7 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/MediaWiki.php(584): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#8 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/MediaWiki.php(435): MediaWiki->main()
#9 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/index.php(46): MediaWiki->run()
#10 {main}
```

If I edit `/includes/filebackend/FileBackendGroup.php` 
and modify LockManager to

```
'lockManager' => 'fsLockManager',
```

and modify permissions as follows:

```
chown -R apache:apache images/
chown -R 755 images/
```

I get the following error:

```
(Could not create directory "mwstore://local-backend/local-public)
```

I've tried most of the forums and there is no solution that seems to fix my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the proper security context type so that SELinux stops complaining.

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /var/www/mediawiki123/images/
```

Don't forget to set the directory back to the correct permissions.

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/mediawiki123/images/
```

For all of your SELinux needs, browse through [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/SELinux#Uploading_Images).

Comment: Also ensure SELinux boolean `httpd_unified` is set to true. It used to default to true, but since RHEL 7 defaults to false.